# RegisterStartupScript doesn't appear to be working on page postback within update panel

Tags: c#, updatepanel, registerstartupscript

OK - so am working on a system that uses a custom datepicker control (I know there are other ones out there.. but for consistency would like to understand why my current issue is happening and fix it).

So its a custom user control with a textbox and on Page_PreRender does this:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string clientScript = @"
        $(function(){
        $('#" + this.Date1.ClientID + @"').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', constrainInput: true});
        });";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), this.ClientID, clientScript, true);

        //Type t = this.GetType();
        //if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(t, this.ClientID))
        //{
        //    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(t, this.ClientID, clientScript, true);
        //}
    }
```

Ignore commented out stuff - that was me trying something different - didn't help.

My issue is that this all works fine when I load the page.  But if I select something from a dropdownlist causing a page postback - when I click into my date fields they stop working.  As in I should be able to click into the textbox and a nice calendar control appears.  But after postback there is no nice calendar control appearing!

It's currently all wrapped (in the hosting page) inside an update panel.  So I comment out the update panel stuff and the dates are working after page postback.  So it appears to be something related to that update panel.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried ScriptManager instead of Page.ClientScript? I looked at some code that I'd written before with UpdatePanels and jQuery and I'd used ScriptManager. I think that the script is not available during a partial postback if it is not registered with the ScriptManager.

Looks like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "DatePickerScript", clientScript, true);
```

Comment: Thanks so much :)  I thought I'd come across this issue before but couldn't remember the alternative!!